# What's the best way to close browser window in AngularJs to to avoid having 'Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it' error?

Tags: angularjs

I need to implement in my controller, a function called by button, which must close the current opened window in my browser. I have tried $window.close() and $window.open(...);$window.close() but these ways of doing things don't work and I have this error : Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.
Please, anyone know a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Use This:**

```
$window.close()
```

**To avoid having 'Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it' error, You'll have to inject the $window service into your controller or service.**

There is also one method, but prefer this in the Angular way and only use injectables method.

***Update 1:***
**To avoid this you have to change from this**

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$window, $modalInstance) {
    .
    .
    .
});
```

**to this.:-**

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope,  $window, $modalInstance) {
    .
    .
    .
}]);
```

Comment: I try this but not works :

angular
        .module('app.widgets.topbar')
        .controller('TopBarController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope,  $window, $modalInstance) {

            $scope.logOut = function(){ 
                $window.close();
            }
        }]);